# в type mongoose задать либо одну схему, либо другую

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**допустим есть 4 схемы:**
`HouseSchema`, `WorkersSchema`, `BrigadesSchema`
и дополнительная схема `BrigadeItemSchema`

```
const HouseSchema = Schema({
  buildingName: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: WorkersSchema || BrigadesSchema } // вопрос в этой строке
})

const WorkersSchema = Schema({
  type: { type: String, enum: ['workers'], required: true },
  items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Worker'}]
})

const BrigadesSchema = Schema({
  type: { type: String, enum: ['brigades'], required: true },
  content: [{ type: BrigadeItemSchema }]
})

// Вспомогательная схема
const BrigadeItemSchema = Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  skillLevel: { type: String, enum: ['junior', 'middle', 'senior'] },
  items: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Worker'}]
})
```

**По сути, весь вопрос сводится к тому,

как задать `type` в `HouseSchema` > `content` либо одной схемы, либо другой?**

---

---

п.с. - в `Typescript` это выглядело бы примерно вот так

```
interface House {
  buildingName: string
  content: Workers | Brigades // вот эту строку нужно реализовать в mongoose
}

interface Workers {
  type: 'workers'
  items: Worker[]
}

interface Worker {
  name: string
  age: number
  profession: string
}

interface Brigades {
  type: 'brigades'
  content: BrigadeItem[]
}

interface BrigadeItem {
  title: string
  skillLevel: 'junior' | 'middle' | 'senior'
  items: Worker[]
}
```

Comment: В вашем случае вам поможет только указание специального типа `Mixed`. Вообще не особо понятно, зачем вы сделали схему workers, когда у вас уже есть схема worker. То же самое и с бригадами.

Comment: @DmitriyGrape для того чтобы в ```House``` > ```content```  был объёкт, с явным указанием типа ```type === 'workers' || type === 'brigades```.  Логика того, что делать с ```House``` > ```content``` > ```items``` зависит от этого типа.